# Jquery Waypoints refresh one waypoint

Tags: jquery-waypoints

Using Waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints) Jquery version, how do you do a refresh of one single waypoint (not all)? I have two waypoints, and only want to refresh one of them. Doable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not doable. You must refresh all waypoints in a Context at the least. I'm curious, why would you **not** want to refresh a waypoint?

Comment: I have redone this a bit, but instead would want to destroy one waypoint (not destroy all). Im trying by using $('#id).waypoint('destroy') but this kills my script. Is that a known issue? thx

Comment: Solved it through using this.destroy(); instead. Thx for a great script!